# Python: Reading characters in ASCII and giving an output with clicks

Tags: python, macos, applescript

I'm fairly new to python so sorry if this is either very basic or alternatively something that is completely impossible to do.

What I'm trying to do is create a script that will read characters then output left or right clicks in ASCII binary according to the character read. Left click being 0s and right clicks being 1s. So the letter A will be 01000001 which will output left-click right-click left-click left-click left-click left-click left-click right-click. Also each character needs to be reversed as well as an extra 1 in front and 10 behind so 'A' is now 11000001010.

This is what I have, which does work (using it as a shell script in applescript) Each click needs a 0.3s delay and each letter a 3s delay.

```
delay 1

set x to 300
set y to 300

do shell script "
/usr/bin/python <<END
import sys
import time
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import *
def mouseEvent(type, posx, posy):
          theEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(None, type, (posx,posy), kCGMouseButtonLeft)
          CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent)
def mousemove(posx,posy):
          mouseEvent(kCGEventMouseMoved, posx,posy);
def rightClick(posx,posy):
          mouseEvent(kCGEventRightMouseDown, posx,posy); 
          mouseEvent(kCGEventRightMouseUp, posx,posy);    
def leftClick(posx,posy):
          mouseEvent(kCGEventLeftMouseDown, posx,posy); 
          mouseEvent(kCGEventLeftMouseUp, posx,posy);             
ourEvent = CGEventCreate(None);
currentpos=CGEventGetLocation(ourEvent);             # Save current mouse position

#reads the letter A in ASCII (01000001)
rightClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #1 Tail
time.sleep(0.3);
rightClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #1 - 8
time.sleep(0.3);
leftClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #0 - 7
time.sleep(0.3);
leftClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #0 6
time.sleep(0.3);
leftClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #0 5
time.sleep(0.3);
leftClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #0 4
time.sleep(0.3);
leftClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #0 - 3
time.sleep(0.3);
rightClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #1 - 2nd bit
time.sleep(0.3);
leftClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #0 - 1st bit
time.sleep(0.3);
rightClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #1 - Leading
time.sleep(0.3);
leftClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #0 - Finish
time.sleep(0.3);
time.sleep(3);

#reads the letter B in ASCII (01000010)
rightClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #1 Tail
time.sleep(0.3);
leftClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #0 - 8
time.sleep(0.3);
rightClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #1 - 7
time.sleep(0.3);
leftClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #1 - 6
time.sleep(0.3);
leftClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #1 - 5
time.sleep(0.3);
leftClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #0 - 4
time.sleep(0.3);
leftClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #0 - 3
time.sleep(0.3);
rightClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #1 - 2nd bit
time.sleep(0.3);
leftClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #0 - 1st bit
time.sleep(0.3);
rightClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #1 - Leading
time.sleep(0.3);
leftClick(" & x & "," & y & "); #0 - Finish
time.sleep(0.3);
time.sleep(3);

mousemove(int(currentpos.x),int(currentpos.y));      # Restore mouse position
END"
```

So what I want to be able to do is either read a .txt file with words in it, or for the program to ask for user to type in words and it will automatically convert to ASCII and all that then start clicking. So would that be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop (for each letter in a string) and another loop (for each character in the binary text)

```
set pos to "300, 300"
set t to quoted form of "AB"

do shell script "/usr/bin/python <<END
import binascii, sys, time
import Quartz.CoreGraphics as qcg
def mouseEvent(type, lrBtn, p):
    theEvent = qcg.CGEventCreateMouseEvent(None, type, (p), lrBtn)
    qcg.CGEventPost(qcg.kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent)
    time.sleep(0.3)
def mousemove(p):
    mouseEvent(qcg.kCGEventMouseMoved, qcg.kCGMouseButtonLeft, p)
def rightClick(lrBtn, p):
    mouseEvent(qcg.kCGEventRightMouseDown, lrBtn, p)
    mouseEvent(qcg.kCGEventRightMouseUp, lrBtn, p)
def leftClick(lrBtn, p):
    mouseEvent(qcg.kCGEventLeftMouseDown, lrBtn, p)
    mouseEvent(qcg.kCGEventLeftMouseUp, lrBtn, p)

tString=" & t & "
pos=" & pos & "
currentpos=qcg.CGEventGetLocation(qcg.CGEventCreate(None))
t = (bin(int(binascii.hexlify(tString),16)))[2:]
ascText = -len(t) % 8 * '0' + t
for i in range(0, len(ascText), 8): ### to every 8 digit 
    ascT = '1' + (ascText[i:i+8])[::-1] + '10'
    for c in ascT:
        if (c=='1'):
            rightClick(qcg.kCGMouseButtonRight, pos)
        else: leftClick(qcg.kCGMouseButtonLeft, pos)

    time.sleep(3);
mousemove(currentpos) # Restore mouse position
END"
```

**Update** :
Convert a space or some other character gives 7 binary digits , the script must add a zero before it.

Instead of checking each character, the script will convert the string , each character gives 8 binary digits, only the first character will be checked.

Use the edited script

Comment: Awesome thanks Jack. Much better load time too, I'm guessing I was loading a whole lot of libraries that weren't needed? Do you know if there is a way to read the " " space character as well (00100000)?